# FFmpeg: Apply Unique Palette To Every Frame of a .GIF?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, gif, animated-gif

⋯

Have `.GIF` with duration of 10 seconds at 15fps, for a total of 150 frames.

Want to use different palette for every frame. Have palette files:

`p1.png`,
`p2.png`,
`p3.png`
etc …
`p150.png`

**- What's my ffmpeg one-liner?**

⋯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paletteuse filter has the option `new` to use a different palette per-frame.

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i file.gif -framerate 15 -i p%d.png -filter_complex paletteuse=new=1 out.gif
```